# Rails: error displaying all projects

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a problem displaying project statuses with relationships.

task.rb model:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_one :status
  has_one :kind


  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 200 }
  validates :alias, length: { maximum: 200 }
  validates :mail_cc, length: { maximum: 200 }
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :keywords, length: { maximum: 200 }
end
```

status.rb model:

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :project
  =begin
    OPEN
    TESTING
    CLOSED
  =end
 validates :value, presence: true
```

end

status have 3 objects with value: a) open b) testing c) closed

projects/index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "New", new_project_path %> |
<%= link_to "Active", projects_path(active: "active") %> |
<%= link_to "All", projects_path %>

<hr>

<h3>Projects</h3>

<hr>

<table class="table table-hover">

<thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Status</th>
     <th>Actions</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
<tr>
  <th><%= link_to project.name, project %></th>
  <th><%= project.status.value %></th>
  <th>
    <%= link_to "Show", '#' %> |
    <%= link_to "Destroy", project_path(project), method: :delete %>
  </th>
</tr>
<% end %>

 </table>
```

It's all working when all have one status. When I create another project with "open" or "testing" or "closed" status I get an error.

[Crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QycR.png)

It create a new project but can't show more than one project with same status.

Comment: If a project must have a status then you could either set a default one or validate it has one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because isn't guaranteed that you'll have at least one `Status` associated with every `Project` you can change the code and use `try` like:

```
<th><%= project.try(:status).try(:value) %></th>
```

This way `try` handles the `no method error`

Comment: ok now its work but not show all statuses, it show just for last project for example i have 3 projects with open status but show just last status from project that i last created}

https://s32.postimg.org/xp2jstdkl/Screenshot_from_2016_07_06_12_12_52.png

storage file, test file, and open they are all open statuses, but showing  status only on last project created with status "open". Its same for testing and closed status

Comment: could you add the model of project?